# javascript method to play an audio form a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm trying to create a chrome console script for a web page that has audio encoded like this

```
<div class="class1" id="id1">
<audio src="linktoaudio" controls="" preload="none" controlslist="nodownload">
</audio>
</div>
```

and produces this piece of html page
[image]

what I need to do is a script that plays the audio and sets its volume at 50%, how to do?

something like this wouldn't work because the audio tag doesn't have an id

```
var audioElem = document.getElementsById("audio");
audioElem.play();
```

Comment: why you don't set the id for the audio tag?

Comment: Use `document.querySelector("#id1 audio")` instead. Basic DOM traversal…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the audio tag is a child of `#id1` you can use `document.querySelector("#id1 audio")`.

To set the volume to 50%, simply use `audioElem.volume = 0.5;`